# How to authorize using Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I have to make a POST request

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @auth.json http://somehost.com/auth
{
    "response": {
        "status": "OK",
        "token": "622cee5f8c99c81e87614e9efc63eddb"
    }
}
```

, and this will return a JSON response with the token. auth.json is a JSON file with login and password. I then have two options: put the token in the header in future requests as "Authorization: TOKEN", or put it in a cookie and make other requests.
How can I do it with Apache Camel? How can I receive HTTP response? Where do I put the token?
Now I have:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
            .to("http://somehost.com/auth");
        }
    });
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    context.stop();
```

}
and I have the auth.json file in ./data/inbox

Answer (score 3):

Since you posted the same question on the Apache Camel mailing list I've provided [an answer](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/How-do-I-authenticate-with-Camel-td4590064.html) there.

To summarize: Just call `setHeader("Authorization", constant("622cee5f8c99c81e87614e9efc63eddb"))` in your route before sending the http request. Camel will automatically translate this header to a transport specific (in this case HTTP) header. Of course you don't need to provide a constant token in your route, you can dynamically calculate or lookup the token by using a Camel [expression](http://camel.apache.org/expression.html) or processor.

Your complete route will look something like:

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() { 
    public void configure() { 
            from("file:data/out?fileName=filename.json&noop=true") 
            .setHeader("Authorization", constant("mytoken")) 
            .to("http://somehost.com/auth"); 
 }
```

Comment: I have tried setting up headers as mentioned by you. But I was unable to pass the headers. I tried using exchange.getOut.setHeaders(headers) but only content-type is getting passed not the authorization header. Any suggestions??